# Extracting untagged text using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a XML file and I'm looking to extract untagged text.

```
<body>
        <p>The prognosis of patients with rectal cancer has improved since the introduction of total mesorectal excision (TME) surgery [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR1">1</xref>&#x02013;
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR3">3</xref>]. Using this surgical technique the mesorectal compartment including the rectum and perirectal fat is completely excised by sharp dissection along the mesorectal fascia (MRF) [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR1">1</xref>]. Additionally, large randomized trials have shown that neo-adjuvant therapy improves local tumor control even further, regardless of optimized surgical techniques [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR3">3</xref>, 
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR4">4</xref>]. The advances in rectal cancer treatment have provoked differentiated neo-adjuvant treatment strategies based on anatomical preoperative identifiable risk factors for local tumor recurrence as can be visualized with magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR5">5</xref>]. One of the most important risk factors is the tumor relationship to the MRF, which actually defines the surgical circumferential resection margin (CRM) in TME surgery [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR6">6</xref>, 
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR7">7</xref>]. Long courses of neo-adjuvant chemoradiation have emerged as the preferential treatment of patients with anticipated tumor invasion of the MRF on MRI in order to downstage/downsize the tumor and to obtain tumor free resection margins [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR5">5</xref>].
            </p>

</body>
```

So the body might contain multiple `<p>` tags.  I am looking to extract text like

> "]. Using this surgical technique the mesorectal compartment including
>   the rectum and perirectal fat is completely excised by sharp
>   dissection along the mesorectal fascia (MRF) ["

, which lies between `CR3` and `CR1` and so on(i.e. between consecutive `xref`). I will also need to add this text to a dictionary which maps the respective `rid` to the list of such texts which follow those `rid`. How can I do this using beautifulsoup and/or regexp.

Comment: Have you got your answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
html = """
<body>
        <p>The prognosis of patients with rectal cancer has improved since the introduction of total mesorectal excision (TME) surgery [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR1">1</xref>&#x02013;
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR3">3</xref>]. Using this surgical technique the mesorectal compartment including the rectum and perirectal fat is completely excised by sharp dissection along the mesorectal fascia (MRF) [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR1">1</xref>]. Additionally, large randomized trials have shown that neo-adjuvant therapy improves local tumor control even further, regardless of optimized surgical techniques [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR3">3</xref>, 
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR4">4</xref>]. The advances in rectal cancer treatment have provoked differentiated neo-adjuvant treatment strategies based on anatomical preoperative identifiable risk factors for local tumor recurrence as can be visualized with magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR5">5</xref>]. One of the most important risk factors is the tumor relationship to the MRF, which actually defines the surgical circumferential resection margin (CRM) in TME surgery [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR6">6</xref>, 
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR7">7</xref>]. Long courses of neo-adjuvant chemoradiation have emerged as the preferential treatment of patients with anticipated tumor invasion of the MRF on MRI in order to downstage/downsize the tumor and to obtain tumor free resection margins [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR5">5</xref>].
            </p>

</body>
"""

import re
re.search('<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR3">3</xref>(.*)', a).group(1)
```

Output is:

```
']. Using this surgical technique the mesorectal compartment including the rectum and perirectal fat is completely excised by sharp dissection along the mesorectal fascia (MRF) ['
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me- It creates a dictionary(mapping)!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d= defaultdict(unicode)

html ='''
<body>
        <p>The prognosis of patients with rectal cancer has improved since the introduction of total mesorectal excision (TME) surgery [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR1">1</xref>&#x02013;
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR3">3</xref>]. Using this surgical technique the mesorectal compartment including the rectum and perirectal fat is completely excised by sharp dissection along the mesorectal fascia (MRF) [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR1">1</xref>]. Additionally, large randomized trials have shown that neo-adjuvant therapy improves local tumor control even further, regardless of optimized surgical techniques [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR3">3</xref>, 
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR4">4</xref>]. The advances in rectal cancer treatment have provoked differentiated neo-adjuvant treatment strategies based on anatomical preoperative identifiable risk factors for local tumor recurrence as can be visualized with magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR5">5</xref>]. One of the most important risk factors is the tumor relationship to the MRF, which actually defines the surgical circumferential resection margin (CRM) in TME surgery [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR6">6</xref>, 
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR7">7</xref>]. Long courses of neo-adjuvant chemoradiation have emerged as the preferential treatment of patients with anticipated tumor invasion of the MRF on MRI in order to downstage/downsize the tumor and to obtain tumor free resection margins [
            <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR5">5</xref>].
            </p>

</body>

'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
l = soup.find_all('xref')
for i in l:
    e= i.next_element
    txt =  e.next_element.encode('utf-8')
    if re.match(r'\].+\[',txt) is not None:
        d[i.attrs['rid'].strip()]=txt.strip()
for k,v in d.items():
    print "The value of {0} is>>>>> {1} ".format(k,v)
```

It prints-

```
The value of CR3 is>>>>> ]. Using this surgical technique the mesorectal compartment including the rectum and perirectal fat is completely excised by sharp dissection along the mesorectal fascia (MRF) [ 
The value of CR1 is>>>>> ]. Additionally, large randomized trials have shown that neo-adjuvant therapy improves local tumor control even further, regardless of optimized surgical techniques [ 
The value of CR7 is>>>>> ]. Long courses of neo-adjuvant chemoradiation have emerged as the preferential treatment of patients with anticipated tumor invasion of the MRF on MRI in order to downstage/downsize the tumor and to obtain tumor free resection margins [ 
The value of CR4 is>>>>> ]. The advances in rectal cancer treatment have provoked differentiated neo-adjuvant treatment strategies based on anatomical preoperative identifiable risk factors for local tumor recurrence as can be visualized with magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) [ 
The value of CR5 is>>>>> ]. One of the most important risk factors is the tumor relationship to the MRF, which actually defines the surgical circumferential resection margin (CRM) in TME surgery [
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out (assuming all your `rid` values starts `CR`):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs(xml) # xml is your xml string text
>>> xml_dict = {'CR' + x.next_element:x.next_sibling.strip() for x in soup.findAll('xref')}
>>> print(xml_dict)

{u'CR3': u',', 
 u'CR1': u']. Additionally, large randomized trials have shown that neo-adjuvant therapy improves local tumor control even further, regardless of optimized surgical techniques [', 
 u'CR6': u',', 
 u'CR7': u']. Long courses of neo-adjuvant chemoradiation have emerged as the preferential treatment of patients with anticipated tumor invasion of the MRF on MRI in order to downstage/downsize the tumor and to obtain tumor free resection margins [', 
 u'CR4': u']. The advances in rectal cancer treatment have provoked differentiated neo-adjuvant treatment strategies based on anatomical preoperative identifiable risk factors for local tumor recurrence as can be visualized with magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) [', 
 u'CR5': u'].'}
```

Comment: what if there are multiple citations for a rid? I would want a mapping to a list of strings.